# How Python handle big number?

Tags: python, biginteger

I have been working with C++ and continuously facing problem of big number.I have solved it with array like "finding factorial of hundred" but I want to know the method of python of handling big number.

Answer (score 0):

(Integer) numbers in python are infinite. They use some block allocation stuff internaly.
Don't worry about big numbers.